# FileNotFoundException on Nexus 4

Tags: android

in my app I need to save some files in the device, to save the file I use:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "mypath"
```

to get the path. This work on almost all the devices but I have some problems in other devices (nexus4 for example..)

the error is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
/mnt/sdcard/musicfall/data/cache/.first_activation: open failed: ENOENT 
(No such file or directory)
```

The strange thing is that it works on many device, and for this reason I can't see the problem.

PS: in "mypath" I use mkdir to create the folders that I need